# Read value from SPI on Raspberry Pi Pico using Rust

Tags: rust, embedded, spi, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to read a value from a sensor, [BMP280](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST-BMP280-DS001-11.pdf) over SPI on a Raspberry Pi Pico. But I am getting an unexpected value.

I created a new repo based on the [rp2040-project-template](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp2040-project-template) and modified it to add SPI functionality.

I added these imports:

```
use embedded_hal::prelude::_embedded_hal_spi_FullDuplex;
use rp_pico::hal::spi;
use rp_pico::hal::gpio;
use fugit::RateExtU32;
```

Then I setup SPI in the bottom of main function:

```
let _spi_sclk = pins.gpio2.into_mode::<gpio::FunctionSpi>();
let _spi_mosi = pins.gpio3.into_mode::<gpio::FunctionSpi>();
let _spi_miso = pins.gpio4.into_mode::<gpio::FunctionSpi>();
let mut spi_cs = pins.gpio5.into_push_pull_output_in_state(PinState::Low); // initial pull down, for SPI

let spi = spi::Spi::<_, _, 8>::new(pac.SPI0);

let mut spi = spi.init(
    &mut pac.RESETS,
    clocks.peripheral_clock.freq(),
    10.MHz(),                           // bmp280 has 10MHz as maximum
    &embedded_hal::spi::MODE_0,
);

spi_cs.set_high().unwrap();   // pull up, set as inactive after init
delay.delay_ms(200);                     // some delay for testing
```

Then I try to read the ID registry

```
spi_cs.set_low().unwrap();
let res_w = spi.send(0xd0 as u8); // 0xd0 is address for ID, with msb 1
let res_r = spi.read();
spi_cs.set_high().unwrap();

// check results
match res_w {
    Ok(_) => info!("write worked"),
    Err(_) => info!("failed to write")
}

match res_r {
    Ok(v) => info!("read value from SPI: {}", v),
    Err(_) => info!("failed to read SPI")
}
```

With this code, the *SPI read fails*. Why is that?

Perhaps it is necessary to set a *mode* on the sensor, before reading the ID. I can add this code above the read, to set *forced mode*.

```
spi_cs.set_low().unwrap();
spi.send(0xf4-128 as u8).expect("failed to send first byte");  // registry 0xf4 with msb 0
spi.send(0x1 as u8).expect("failed to send second byte");
spi_cs.set_high().unwrap();
```

Now the read of *ID registry* works, but I get value `255` and not the expected `0x58`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have also tried with `transfer` using this code:

```
let mut data: [u8; 2] = [0xd0, 0x0];
let transfer_success = spi.transfer(&mut data);
match transfer_success {
    Ok(v) => info!("read data {}", v),
    Err(_) => info!("failed to read")
}
```

But I read the values as `[255, 255]` with this code, not the expected `0x58`.

Comment: Your handling of chip-select looks a bit odd. It should always be a push-pull output. You seem to be configuring as an input (with a pull resistor?)

Comment: @pmacfarlane you are right. I have updated my code. That was one of my misunderstandings, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`read()`](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/spi/struct.Spi.html#method.read) is probably not the function you want to use here; it doesn't acutally perform any bus action but only gives you the byte that was read during the last [`send()`](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/spi/struct.Spi.html#method.send).

The function you actually want to use is [`transfer()`](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/spi/struct.Spi.html#method.transfer%60). On a full-duplex SPI bus, a "read" action is **always** also a "write" action, and `transfer` performs both. Be aware that if you **only** want to read, you need to **write** the same amount of zeros, because only the bus master can provide the clock to do anything.

So if you want to write `0xd0`, followed by reading a single byte, you need to `transfer()` the values `[0xd0, 0x00]`. The **same array** that you use to put your sent data into `transfer()` will then contain the received data; most likely `[0x00, <data>]` (or `[0xff, <data>]`, not sure. Probably `0xff`, as you already mentioned that you read a `255`).

The [implementation of `transfer`](https://docs.rs/embedded-hal/0.2.7/src/embedded_hal/blocking/spi.rs.html#39-54) shows how `read()` is **actually** supposed to be used:

```rust
fn transfer<'w>(&mut self, words: &'w mut [W]) -> Result<&'w [W], S::Error> {
    for word in words.iter_mut() {
        block!(self.send(word.clone()))?;
        *word = block!(self.read())?;
    }

    Ok(words)
}
```

Note the `block!()` here - in embedded, asynchronous calls usually return an error indicating that the operation would block, until it is finished. The `block!()` macro converts an asynchronous call to a blocking call, which is most likely where your error comes from.

Either way, I would recommend deriving your code from the [official example](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal/blob/main/rp2040-hal/examples/spi.rs), those are usually pretty good at demonstrating the intended way an object should be used.

Comment: I tried with `transfer` now, but I got `[255, 255]` as value. I am expecting `0x58`.

Comment: @Jonas Well, I tried. I sadly cannot help you any further as I don't have a BMP280 on hand. Next steps I could think of: 1) read the sensor documentation to see if you need to do something to enable the SPI interface of the sensor first. 2) look at the traffic with a logic analyzer or an oscilloscope, to see what is happening on the bus, and whether your code has a problem or the device isn't answering. I personally usually use a Saleae Logic 8 (because I found one cheap online and like the interface)

Comment: Ok, I got `[255, 88]` after adding code to manage `spi_cs` before and after the `transfer`.

Comment: @Jonas Happy to hear :) Yes, my next step would have been to look at the bus with a logic analyzer, and then one would probably have realized that the `CS` connection doesn't trigger properly. Glad to hear it's working now :)

Comment: I think the key info here was the use of `block!()` otherwise this code looks similar to the one I provided.

Comment: @Jonas Partially; I think the two things were `block!()` and the fact that you have to `send(0)` before calling `read()`. You were only reading the byte during the previous `send` and were never actually giving the device the chance to answer.